# SQL wild card selection

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to figure out the top customers based on one condition - whether they are direct users by the `memo` column in `transaction` table. IF the memo includes words such as `PAYROLL`,`PAYRLL`,`SALARY` and `transaction_type = 'Credit'`, they are considered as top customers. Thus, I wrote query below:

```
SELECT user_id, 
   CASE WHEN transaction_type = 'Credit' AND 
                 (memo LIKE '%PAYROLL%' OR memo LIKE '%PAYRLL%' OR memo LIKE '%SALARY%') 
            THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS TOP_USERS
FROM transaction
```

However, I saw a person who should be 1 but still counted as 0 in this column.
Is there something wrong with my wild card?
I am using PostgreSQL pgadmin3

Comment: I don't see any glaring error with the wildcards, but that's all I can say from the information given.  It might help if we knew the values of TRANSACTION_TYPE and MEMO for the record that you expect should match but isn't

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger this person who counted as 0 has records of 'Credit' under transaction_type and 'AMERICAN AIRLINE PAYRLL DEP' under memo

Comment: Could the `transaction_type` field allow extra whitespace? Maybe the one that wasn't counted is actually `'Credit              '`?

Comment: @elmer007 I tried the extra space but this person is still counted as 0...

Comment: Could this be an issue of capitalization or unprintable characters?

Comment: @GordonLinoff no, because all texts are upper case within database so that i use upper case in my code

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment that the person "has records of 'Credit' under transaction_type and 'AMERICAN AIRLINE PAYRLL DEP' under memo" are those the same records? Does 'AMERICAN AIRLINE PAYRLL DEP' show up in memo in the same record where the type is 'Credit' or are they separate records? If they are separate changing the AND to OR would solve it.

Comment: Hi there, we need to satisfy both conditions instead of one.

Comment: I understand you need to satisfy both. As your wildcards appear to be correct, we are left figuring out why the person wasn't returned by your query. The two most likely explanations, while the person has records that meet each of the criteria, they don't have any records that meet both, or the 'Credit' in transaction_type isn't the same as the 'Credit' in your query. Hence, the comments about whitespace and capitalization.